# ¿Para qué sirve el atributo directives dentro de un componente?

Tags: typescript, angular

Pues eso, no me queda claro para que sirve el atributo directives de un componente y si me pueden dar un ejemplo:

```
@Component({
    selector:    'todo-list',
    templateUrl: 'todo-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['todo-list.component.css'],      
    directives:  [Algo],
})
```

Comment: Que version de angular utilizas? [No existe tal parametro para el decorador @Component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component), por lo menos no en la version 2 - 5.2

Comment: Uso la version 4